# Rearrange vertices

Tags: vertices, sculpting, meta-objects

I've just been aware of the existence of the "metaball-mesh" which seems very interesting, but when converted into a mesh, the vertices are arranged really messy, and it doesn't even mirror correctly.

You can see an example of this in the picture below.

Sometimes I encounter a similar problem when sculpting or using the decimate-tool.

What I need is a tool that keeps the shape as intact as possible, while rearranging the vertices in a way, so that they are evenly spaced (approximately) so that all faces are about the same size. Does Blender have a tool for that? Or do you have other suggestions that don't require me to rearrange every vertice manually?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use retopology techniques to get a cleaner mesh to work with if you are planning to texture and animate this mesh. It would be faster to just box model something like this. Metaballs can help with creating a base mesh for working with Dynotopo in sculpt mode but you'll eventually have retopo it as the next step.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.